# Why does my project have no build.sbt file?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've created a project in sbt, however there is no `build.sbt` or even `Build.scala` included in the project. Am I supposed to create my own build files?

Comment: How did you create the project?

Comment: sbt in the command line

Comment: Could you explain how exactly? What command did you execute?

Comment: He just ran sbt in the directory with src, which works fine by convention. No actual project was created, i.e. no project specific files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SBT works by convention (like Maven) and you don't have to have a project file for it. If your project is very small and does not require any dependencies or custom settings you can get by without creating a project file.

For small projects that need dependencies use `build.sbt` and for large projects (with subprojects) use `Build.scala`.

More info here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Hello.html

Comment: So I should create my own build.sbt file?
Also in doing so, should my library dependencies be located inside a class or just in the file on their own?

Comment: like I said you don't have to, but usually you would want to. It will also help IDEs to know what type of project that is: IntelliJ -> import project.

Comment: example of a `build.sbt`: https://github.com/izmailoff/Scala-Is-Awesome/blob/master/build.sbt. Example of a `Build.scala` and related files: https://github.com/izmailoff/remote-akka-server-template/tree/master/project

Comment: if you use `build.sbt` there is no explicit object or class, as you can see in the example. If you use full blown `Build.scala` then dependencies are located in that class.

Comment: At a minimum you want a project/build.properties.   That may become a requirement soon.

Comment: Thanks @jsuereth for bringing this up